# Making a delay in C with 20MHz crystal(beginner level)

Tags: c, delay, interrupt, pic

I've recently started with C and Im trying to figure out how to make a 10ms delay for
PIC16F884. From the formulas in the datasheet I've managed to create the following:

fosc = 20MHz and Toscx4 = 200ns

If I put a preset to 100 => t=100x200ns=20us and to get a 10 ms delay

10ms/20us = 500

Will the following code in C give me what Im looking for (10ms delay)? Assume I have all the initiating code and variables.

```
void interrupt ISR(void){

     if(TMR0IF){
        TMR0IF=0;
        counter++;
     }
     if(counter==100){
        delay++;
        counter=0;
     }
}

int main(void){

    TMR0=155;

    if(delay>4){
    //any code
    delay=0;
    }
}
```

Might be a bad example but hopefully you understand

Comment: If there aren't watchdog timers in place, you can test this yourself by trying to implement a 1 second (for example) delay. If your 1 second delay is accurate, you should be able to divide your counters by 100 to get a 10 ms delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since the code in `main()` never actually *waits*, it won't implement a delay.

Assuming the interrupt and timer logic is properly set up, you're still going to need to loop:

```
delay = 0;
TMR0 = 155; /* Start timer. */
while(delay < 4)
  ; /* Do nothing */
/* More code here, delay has expired */
```

Also, remember to make `delay` a `volatile`  variable since you're accessing it from multiple parallel threads of execution.

Comment: Can I use a loop like while(1) and inside that loop use if(delay>4)?

Comment: @user3660570 Yes. Why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 0):

If you're a really beginner and want a tool that can help you calculate timer settings I advise you to look at this link :
http://www.mikroe.com/timer-calculator/

It generate the ccode for settiing properly a lot of different microcontroller